# Entity Framework 6 TPH Inheritance Enum Field Generate Slow Query

Tags: performance, entity-framework, enums, casting

I use EF 6.0 code first and TPH inheritance in my project. I see that if i use enum field in my classes EF generates sql statement with casting. So my query runs very slowly and performance is down.  How can i remove casting in my sql query?

Thanks.

```
var db = new AppContext();
var p = db.Products.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ProdId == 1);


public enum MyEnum
{
    Field1 = 1,
    Field2 = 2
}

public class Product
{
    [Key]
    public int ProdId { get; set; }

    public string ProdName { get; set; }

    //I run my code with this property and without this property.
    //public MyEnum MyEnum { get; set; }
}

public class Chair : Product
{
    public string ChairProp1 { get; set; }
}

public class Seat : Product
{
    public string SeatProp1 { get; set; }
}

//EF generate this SQL without enum field. This is good SQL statements.
SELECT TOP (1) 
[Extent1].[Discriminator] AS [Discriminator], 
[Extent1].[ProdId] AS [ProdId], 
[Extent1].[ProdName] AS [ProdName], 
[Extent1].[ChairProp1] AS [ChairProp1], 
[Extent1].[SeatProp1] AS [SeatProp1]
FROM [dbo].[Products] AS [Extent1]
WHERE ([Extent1].[Discriminator] IN (N'Chair',N'Seat',N'Product')) AND (1 = [Extent1].[ProdId])


//EF generate this SQL with enum field (myenum). there is alot of casting.i want to remove casting.
SELECT 
[Limit1].[C1] AS [C1], 
[Limit1].[ProdId] AS [ProdId], 
[Limit1].[ProdName] AS [ProdName], 
[Limit1].[MyEnum] AS [MyEnum], 
[Limit1].[C2] AS [C2], 
[Limit1].[C3] AS [C3]
FROM ( SELECT TOP (1) 
    [Extent1].[ProdId] AS [ProdId], 
    [Extent1].[ProdName] AS [ProdName], 
    [Extent1].[MyEnum] AS [MyEnum], 
    CASE WHEN ([Extent1].[Discriminator] = N'Product') THEN '0X' WHEN ([Extent1].[Discriminator] = N'Chair') THEN '0X0X' ELSE '0X1X' END AS [C1], 
    CASE WHEN ([Extent1].[Discriminator] = N'Product') THEN CAST(NULL AS varchar(1)) WHEN ([Extent1].[Discriminator] = N'Chair') THEN [Extent1].[ChairProp1] END AS [C2], 
    CASE WHEN ([Extent1].[Discriminator] = N'Product') THEN CAST(NULL AS varchar(1)) WHEN ([Extent1].[Discriminator] = N'Chair') THEN CAST(NULL AS varchar(1)) ELSE [Extent1].[SeatProp1] END AS [C3]
    FROM [dbo].[Products] AS [Extent1]
    WHERE ([Extent1].[Discriminator] IN (N'Chair',N'Seat',N'Product')) AND (1 = [Extent1].[ProdId])
)  AS [Limit1]
```

Comment: Can you upgrade to 6.1.3?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you missed the configuration of discriminator . You need to specify which field is the discriminator and what's the type of that ,

You can do it by fluent api like this :

```
public class ChairConfig : EntityTypeConfiguration<Chair>
{
    public ChairConfig()
    {
        this.Map(m => m.Requires(discriminator: "MyEnum").HasValue(MyEnum.Field1));
    }
}

public class SeatConfig : EntityTypeConfiguration<Seat>
{
    public SeatConfig()
    {
        this.Map(m => m.Requires(discriminator: "MyEnum").HasValue(MyEnum.Field2));
    }
}
```

And in query you need to specify which type you wanna retrieve like this :

```
var db = new AppContext();
var p = db.Products.OfType<Chair>().FirstOrDefault(x => x.ProdId == 1);
```

Comment: No, this is not the issue. As you see, the discriminator is queried.